# Trying to Categorize XML data in a PHP Shopping Cart

Tags: php, html, xml

Ok, so I'm attempting to create a PHP based shopping cart reading from an XML file for the catalogue. The only problem is when I print out the information onto my website, it prints out EVERYTHING in the XML file. I need to put them into categories (i.e. shoes, apparel, etc.) and only print out the called category.

The XML file is structured as such (extra spaces added for organizational purposes):

```
<items>
    <product>
        <id>           TSHIRT01                        </id>
        <title>        Red T-Shirt                     </title>
        <category>     apparel                         </category>
        <description>  T-Shirt designed by Sassafrass  </description>
        <img>          ../images/apparel1.jpg          </img>
        <price>        5.99                            </price>
    </product>
</items>
```

I print out the information onto my website using the following code:

```
<?php echo render_products_from_xml(); ?>
```

And here's the function for that PHP command that just sets the structure for it being output onto the website itself:

```
function render_products_from_xml(){
$counter=0;
$output = '<table class="products"> <tr>';
foreach(get_xml_catalog() as $product)
{
    $counter++;
    $output .='

                <td>
                    <div class="title">
                    <h2> '.$product->title.' </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cells">
                        <img src="'.$product->img.'" height="220" width="170" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                    <span>
                        '.$product->description.'
                    </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="price">
                        $'.$product->price.'
                    </div>
                    <div class="addToCart">
                        <a href="addToCart.php?id='.$product->id.'">Add To Cart</a>
                    </div>
                </td>';
    if($counter%4 == 0)
    {
        $output .='<tr>';
    }
}
$output .='</tr></table>';
return $output;}
```

I was hoping to have the PHP function end up looking something like this (changes made in all caps):

```
<?php echo render_products_from_xml($CATEGORY=='APPAREL'); ?>
```

or something along these lines:

```
<?php echo render_APPAREL_products_from_xml(); ?>
```

Just need some tips on how I can add some functions to help categorize the information read from the XML file.
Also, I don't want to create new XML files for each category because I'll need to duplicate all my codes to pull information from the separate XML files and consolidate all the products into one shopping cart. I'm looking for something a lot easier to manage.

And on a final note, I have a lot of background functions working in the back just grabbing information and setting up the actual shopping cart itself, so if you feel the need for me to give you more code, just ask! Also, if I was vague about anything, don't hesitate telling me so I can (hopefully) correct the problem or answer your question.

Thanks for much in advance for all the help you can give! I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: why an xml file and not  a DB?

Comment: @Dagon Someone suggested I use XML as a database so I can easily alter the information inside whenever I need to change the products. Being a beginner programmer, that seemed like the best idea. So I took it and ran.

Comment: @Dagon What's the difference between using an XML file and a DB? Like pros and cons.

Comment: a db would be easier, a lot easier. why not look at one of the many existing applications that do this.

Comment: @Dagon Sounds like a plan. Just looked at the difference between the two and it looks as if DB's already categorize everything. Do you know of any good websites or books that can help a beginner begin understanding and using DB's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't show the function `get_xml_catalog()`, which is apparently fetching the XML.

So with the code you've given, you could make relatively small changes to the function `render_products_from_xml()`:

```
function render_products_from_xml($category) {
    $counter=0;
    $output = '<table class="products"> <tr>';

    foreach (get_xml_catalog() as $product) {

        if ((string)$product->category == $category || $category == '') {

            $counter++;
            $output .= 'all that stuff'; 

            if ($counter % 4 == 0) $output .= '<tr>';
        } // if
    } // foreach

    $output .='</tr></table>';
    return $output;
}
```

**Comments:**

(1) now call that function by passing the parameter `$category`:

```
echo render_products_from_xml('apparel');
```

(2) within the `foreach` loop, only a `<product>` with its category == `$category` is added to `$output`.

(3) if `$category` is an empty string, every `<product>` is added to `$output`.

**Alternative:**

Change function `get_xml_catalog($category)` to do the selection at that place. This will probably be done best with `xpath`.